# How to get each input box value and corresponding text string into a CSV file

Tags: php, forms, csv

I am attempting to create an order form on our website but I have hit a dead end and am not sure where to go next.

I have a php file that queries a database and returns a list of item numbers and the quantity we have in stock.  For each item number that shows up in the table there is an input box next to it.  At the moment these input boxes all have the same Id.
My guess would be that first I need to have it so they don't all have the same ID?
Here is the form in action: http://synergysystems.com.au/soh/testmysql.php

From there, the user will fill out the form and click a submit button.  This will then need to get the values from the input boxes (if greater than or equal to 1) and the corresponding item number and create a CSV file.  The CSV file would just be 1st column - item number 2nd column - quantity.

I have attempted to do this with code I have found on the internet but just cant get my head around how I would go through each input box and get the values as well as the item number.

I think I may be going about it the wrong way.

Here is my current php to create the form:

```
    <?php
    echo "<div id=header>";
    echo "<h1>Synergy Order Form</h1>";
    echo "<p>Stock is updated every hour during business hours</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='table.css' type='text/css'>";



$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '*****', '*****');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('****',$conn);
    /*  select only items with stock on hand */
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_SOH where (((TABLE_SOH.ITM_ONHAND) >0))",$conn);

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>On Hand</th>
<th>Order Quantity</>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ITM_NO'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ITM_DES'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=right>" . $row['ITM_ONHAND'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". ("<input type ='text' name ='Item'.$i >") . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($conn);



?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="submit_order.php">
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
</form>
```

I don't have anything in the submit_order.php file as I have gutted it out of frustration trying to get something to work.

Even if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: "<input type ='text' name ='Item'.$i >" is going to come out weird. Are you sure you want the resulting html to be, <input type='text' name='Item'.$i>

Comment: To be honest I don't know. Is there anything else you would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is get all the data in all the input fields, you can just loop through $_POST in submit_order.php and toss them into the CSV.

```
// unset the stuff you dont want
unset($_POST['submit']);

// open a file
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

// put the items in the file
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    if($key > 1)
        fputcsv($fp, array($key, $val));

// Close the file
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've attempted the provided code but I only get an empty CSV file.  I've attempted to make some adjustments but couldn't get it to work out.  Thanks again.